# Using Scons to build mongo-nonx86 on an arm based Synology NAS

Tags: mongodb, arm, scons

I have a Synology DS212j NAS (cpu Feroceon 88FR131 rev 1 (v5l)) with the optware ipkg installed. I am trying to build mongo-nonx86 on it.

"scons all" gives me the following messages:

> scons: Reading SConscript files ...
>
> scons version: 2.0.1
>
> python version: 2 5 6 'final' 0
>
> Checking whether the C++ compiler worksyes
>
> Checking for C library stdc++... no
>
> can't find stdc++ library which is needed

I have the stdc++ library installed, I also have ssl installed. My underlying question is how can I get scons to tell me more about what is really missing, where it is looking, how it is looking etc. I have so far found no options which generate any more useful diagnostic output?

Obviously a ready-made solution for getting mongodb working on this great little box would be even more welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well even if you do have it installed, it doesn't seem to think so, here is what I would try to do, install `libssl-dev`, then try to install the dev package for `libstdc++`, which is: libstdc++-dev.

Then see if you can compile it.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, in the strict sense you have answered my immediate question: libstdc++-dev is not there when I say "ipkg list | grep stdc" - just plain old libstdc++, which is then all I have installed. So I suppose that is my problem. So who do I call now?

Comment: @markandrew Synology might help, however third party apps through ipkg are not supported by them, that includes if they break your NAS. But they might find it in themselves to help.